# What's the heter to ask a non jew to fix a sukkah on yom tov

Tags: gentiles, melacha-creative-work, yom-tov, sukkah, derabanan

The Mishnah Berurah [637:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.637.1) says its forbidden to build a sukkah on yom tov or to fix the schach if it fell off. However, through a non jew יש להתיר, he says it's permissible.

Im curious what is the heter. My impression is building a sukkah is a melacha doraisa, either binyan, or at least setting up the schach should be the melacha of ohel. My understanding is the issur derabanan of asking a non jew to do melacha is alleviated when it's שבות דשבות במקום מצוה, when you're asking them to break a derabanan for the  sake of a mitzvah ([SA 307:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.307.5)). Here if the melacha is doraisa, how can you ask them? Or does he mean hint to them (not sure if that helps)? Or here since it's the issue of not having a sukkah, there's more leeway?

Comment: Perhaps it's the Ittur that even for Deoraytas you can ask. See OC 276:2 and this is probably a Tzorekh Gadol

Comment: 307:5 even actually references that opinion

Comment: My impression when I wrote this question was that opinion isn't usually relied upon

Comment: Indeed it isn't usually relied upon. This isn't a usual situation

Comment: The Ittur is not a solitary opinion (da'at yechida'ah)